# How do I filter the dates of the current week from a general date list in Javascript or Typescript?

Tags: javascript, date, typescript

I have an array that contains multiple Dates and, from this array, I want to return an array that contains only the Dates that belong to the current week. How can I do this?

Comment: Define *"list"* ... html, array ,other? Please take some time to read through [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: What is the format of the dates?

Comment: @charlietfl, an array

Comment: Do some research and spend time a little. Start by getWeek

Comment: @sissonb I'm working with the Date class

Comment: @Volem there is no `.getWeek()` method on the Date prototype.

Comment: That is right but do research on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only hard part about this is finding the time frame of the week. To do that you could do:

```js
function getWeekDates() {

  let now = new Date();
  let dayOfWeek = now.getDay(); //0-6
  let numDay = now.getDate();

  let start = new Date(now); //copy
  start.setDate(numDay - dayOfWeek);
  start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);


  let end = new Date(now); //copy
  end.setDate(numDay + (7 - dayOfWeek));
  end.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  return [start, end];
}

let [start, end] = getWeekDates();

console.log(start.toLocaleString(), end.toLocaleString());
```

Now, to filter them:

```js
function filterDatesByCurrentWeek(dates){
   let [start, end] = getWeekDates();
   return dates.filter(d => +d >= +start && +d < +end);
}
```

This is assuming your dates are date objects. If they are not, you'll need a way to parse them and get the date object.

Comment: Omg, you're a genius. I think this is exactly what I am looking for. I'll make some test and then give you a feedback. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @flpn, I made a small update I think it's clearer this way. The only difference is with the end date object, which is the beginning of the next week instead of being the last millisecond of the week. Changed the predicate function too, so it doesn't include the date, just until that date

Comment: Shouldn't `end.setDate(numDay + (7 - dayOfWeek));` be `end.setDate(numDay + (6 - dayOfWeek));` ?

Comment: @sissonb, that would put you at the last day of the week (in the morning). I wanted it to be next week (so in 7 days).

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: A question: why are "+" symbols necessary inside the filter function?

Comment: @flpn, they convert the date objects (d, start, end) to numeric timestamps which can be compared easily with `>` and `<`

Comment: @flpn The + converts the Date object into a number. Basically calls Date.getTime()

Comment: So if my list of dates is already in the form of numbers I just need to convert the "start" and "end", right? Interesting...

Comment: @flpn, yes, you don't need to remove the `+`s (since it's basically a no-op) but if they are always numbers just remove the `+` for `d`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).

You could easily filter the array by doing

```
var currentDate = moment();
var allDates = [...];
var filtered = allDates.filter(date => moment(date).isSame(currentDate, 'week');
```

Comment: There's no other way for doing this without this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
let outOfWeek = new Date();
outOfWeek.setDate(outOfWeek.getDate() + 7)

const dateList = [
  new Date(),
  outOfWeek
]
const monthDay = new Date().getDate();
const weekDay = new Date().getDay();
const daysToSunday = 7 - weekDay;
const daysFromSunday = weekDay;

const setDateToMidnight = (date) =>{
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);
}

let maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setDate(monthDay + daysToSunday);
setDateToMidnight(maxDate);

let minDate = new Date();
minDate.setDate(monthDay - daysFromSunday);
setDateToMidnight(minDate);

filteredDates = dateList.filter((date) => {
  if (date.getTime() < maxDate.getTime() && date.getTime() >= minDate.getTime()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
})

console.log(dateList);
console.log(filteredDates);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qorb6ruL/5/

Comment: I appreciate the response but you did not understand my problem well. I need to filter the dates that are within my current week.

Comment: You can zero all the time parts in one call with `minDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)`. A lot less typing.

Comment: @RobG Good point. I try to be as verbose as possible when I write examples on here and I don't think it's as readable to set the minutes, seconds and milliseconds in a method called `setHours`.